# {Page_Name}?fields=id,name,posts.fields(message,created_time,comments) Can't retrieve comments from Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, data-retrieval

I used to Retrieve the comments of my page using Graph API & FB API
and i didn't made any change for the Code

Expected Behavior to retrieve post information and its Comments (with its information) including (message)
Actual Behavior only the posts are retrieved With no Comments (message)

it was working on v9.0 Graph API from a couple of months and
now none of the versions retrieve the comments on the posts

Also v11.0 for clicking on next page link gives me that error (v9.0 not doing that behavior)
{
"error": {
"message": "Unknown path components: /768796853148621/posts",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 2500,
"fbtrace_id": "
Abya1pK7qVPlMxxz655qMFG
"
}
}

Also for v13.0 facing the same problem

```
Page_name=Page_name_
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token_1,version="3.2")
    feilds=["id","name","posts.fields(message,created_time,comments.since(2021-05-08).until(2021-06-01))"]
    posts = graph.get_object(Page_name, fields=feilds,)
    print("############################# comments.............")
    real_posts = posts['posts']['data']
    print(real_posts)
    next_comments =  requests.get(posts['posts']["paging"]["next"]).json()
    next_real_posts=next_comments['data']
    print(next_real_posts)
    list_next_posts=[]
    while True:
        try:   
            next_comments =  requests.get(next_comments["paging"]["next"]).json()
            next_real_posts=next_comments['data']
            list_next_posts.append(next_real_posts)

        except:
            break
```